# Why do my renders have noise / don't look sharp?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I feel like my renders are not very sharp. You definitely notice this when you zoom in a little bit, as you can see by my picture below.

In the second picture you can see a bit of my render settings. I feel like the max samples of 1024 should be fine to give me a sharp image.
(I am rendering via CPU since I am on a MacBook)

Why is it not sharp?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This image is displayed on the page at its native resolution, every pixel you rendered is represented 1:1 on the screen.  When you zoom in, the computer doesn't construct new pixels to fill in the details of the image, those existing pixels are just enlarged

Comment: If you want an image that maintains quality on zoom, you have to render a high resolution image and that gets initially displayed at a smaller scale.  Then the user has some headroom if they decide to zoom in

Comment: So what do you mean by high resolution image? Because now I am working with 1600x1200, or do you mean rendering with 4096 samples for example?

Comment: I threw a couple of ideas out there.  Does this happen in other files?

Comment: 1600x1200 pixels isn't that big. You will quickly see the pixels. You can kind of make it less obvious by increasing the Pixel Filter width, but you can't get too far with this without making it look like a blurry image. If you want mode detailed edges without bluring too much, you need to go beyond 1600x1200.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the details of the image, there must be something happening to pixelate the output.  Check here:

[image]

And check in the compositor for anything happening there.  You could have used a pixelate node and scaled the image, perhaps.